# Multiple GL textures (real time) rendering speed is too slow

Tags: opengl-es, textures

I'm going to draw 2 textures at the same time. (from different videos, getting different frame textures in real time...)
It works well and the code is below.

```
// module 1---------------
{
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);
    int bufferHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraFrame);
    int bufferWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cameraFrame);

    // Create a new texture from the camera frame data, display that using the shaders
    glGenTextures(1, &videoFrameTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, videoFrameTexture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // This is necessary for non-power-of-two textures
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // Using BGRA extension to pull in video frame data directly
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cameraFrame));
}
{
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(buf2, 0);
    int bufferHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(buf2);
    int bufferWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(buf2);
    // Create a new texture from the camera frame data, display that using the shaders
    glGenTextures(1, &videoFrameTexture2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, videoFrameTexture2);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // This is necessary for non-power-of-two textures
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // Using BGRA extension to pull in video frame data directly
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(buf2));
}

[self drawFrame]; // module2---------

{
    glDeleteTextures(1, &videoFrameTexture);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &videoFrameTexture2);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(buf2, 0);
}
```

But its speed is too slow. Mainly module2 is slow.
I checked about glTexSubImage2D instead of glTexImage2D, but no good result.

Is there any solution to speed up?

Comment: Do you really do all this texture object creation/destruction at each frame?

Comment: I know its bad, so please let me know the solution. Why did people downvote without the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

I got solution, I called glGenTextures only once at first, and draw in loop. Speed doubled now. And I'll replace the glTexImage2D with glTexSubImage2D. And I deleted the glDeleteTextures!

CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef, This is the awesome key for speed-up! almost real time!!!